# Using pyROOT in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, pyroot

I would like to use a pyROOT module in my software under the pycharm IDE. 
My problem is that the IDE doesn't recognize any of root modules. 
Can you tell me what should I do to fix this issue?

Comment: Can you please give us a bit more information, such as a stacktrace?

Comment: do you have pyRoot installed?

Comment: What do you mean by "recognize"? Does your python code not work because of missing ROOT classes or do only things like tab-completion not work? If the latter: check http://stackoverflow.com/q/5049842/2319400

Comment: @sebastian I mean  tab-completion.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yes of course. I can use it by the python interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22683308/is-it-possible-to-easily-extract-python-run-configuration-with-additional-path), you can probably fix this by doing;

"If you select the correct project and go to File > Settings, under the Project Settings you can see the Project Interpreter which tells you which interpreter is being used."

Once you've selected to the correct interpreter, you'll also need to install PYRoot as explained [here](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/pyroot).

You can install rootpy bindings using pip, explained [here](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing.html) and [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rootpy/).

Comment: PyROOT won't be found on pip. rootpy is something different - it's another layer on top of pyROOT.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize. Modified answer accordingly.